# How do i define the range of SDKs that my app can run on

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I want my app to run from SDK 21 till the latest version of SDK, I defined the min sdk version to 21 and target sdk to 26, but then I ran the app on a 28 api phone and it required I download a package. will this happen when I upload it to google play store?

Comment: It will support the higher version but there could be API/behaviour changes of higher version of sdk which your app might not be supporting. But when you are setting target version that means you are telling user that app will completely compatible with the target SDK version and compiled / tested against it. Your app will be still able to run on higher version with Android default backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot man got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run normaly on higher APIs. I have never had problems with it and I published 3 games made in android studio.